# Wifi is working but I can't open "Wifi Settings"

Tags: 18.04, gnome, system-settings

I have my WiFi connections and VPN working without any problem. But I can't open "Wi-Fi Settings" or "VPN Settings" from the drop-down menu in the right corner of the panel.

[image: That's where I'm clicking].

Whenever I click the menu option nothing happens.

My Ubuntu is 18.04.1 LTS.

I searched this problem here and Google but I couldn't find anything due to the large amount of "Wi-Fi is not working" posts.

Also I wasn't been able to reach the same app through the command line or the Activities however I'm not sure if I get the name right (I searched Network, Wi-Fi, Settings among other phrases).

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean network and wifi settings are missing from settings? What do you get if you run `gnome-control-center wifi`? Have you tried reinstalling gnome-control-center using `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`?

Comment: I reinstalled gnome-control-center and worked. Thank you very much. I didn't know the name of the app.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I reinstalled the control center with

`sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center`

As suggested in comments by @Kulfy.  This fixed the problem.

Comment: Just a little follow up to the good tip "sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center" It may not be that easy to reinstall something when you are not connected to the internet. If you are on a virtual pc you may add another network nic, then run the command. The new network nic will in most cases show up with dhcp enabled, and hopefully you will be able to connect to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

it may fail once run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then again run the first command and it will work